# Apply defaults to a map

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for a way to apply some defaults to map. I know the following works:

```
(defn apply-defaults
  [needing-defaults]
  (merge {:key1 (fn1 10)
          :key2 (fn2 76)}
          needing-defaults))
```

The issue with the above is that the value of `fn1` and `fn2` are evaluated even though `needing-defaults` might already have these keys - thus never needing them.

I've tried with merge-with but that doesn't seem to work. I'm quite new at this - any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm ussually applying defaults with merge-with function:

```
(merge-with #(or %1 %2) my-map default-map)
```

But in your case it should be something like:

```
(reduce (fn [m [k v]]
          (if (contains? m k) m (assoc m k (v))))
        needing-defaults
        defaults)
```

where `defaults` is a map of functions:

```
{ :key1 #(fn1 10)
  :key2 #(fn2 76)}
```

`if` is a special form, so it newer evaluates its `false` branch.

[See my example for more info](https://gist.github.com/lbeschastny/6645560).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, how about this?

```
(defn apply-defaults [nd]
    (into {:key1 (sf1 10) :key2 (sf2 76)} nd))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. No mater if the keys exist in `nd` the functions `sf1` and `sf2` are evaluated (you can see this easy if you add side effects ie. `println`).

Comment: I think I misunderstood the intent of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can merge `nil` into a map, you can use the `if-not` macro:

```
(merge {} nil {:a 1} nil) ;; {:a 1}
```

Try this:

```
(defn apply-defaults [col]
  (merge col
    (if-not (contains? col :key1) {:key1 (some-function1 10)})
    (if-not (contains? col :key2) {:key2 (some-function2 76)})))
```

`some-function1` and `some-function2` will only be executed when `col` does not already have the key.

Comment: Though the function becomes very verbose, it gets the job done.
Gonna wait until tomorrow in the hope that a more lean solution exists and someone can come up with it :) If not the answer goes to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro to generate the `contains?` checks and short circuit the function calls.

```
(defmacro merge-with-defaults [default-coll coll]
  (let [ks (reduce (fn [a k] (conj a
                                   `(not (contains? ~coll ~k))
                                   `(assoc ~k ~(k default-coll))))
                   [] (keys default-coll))]
    `(cond-> ~coll ~@ks)))


(defn apply-defaults [needing-defaults]
  (merge-with-defaults {:key1 (fn1 10)
                        :key2 (fn2 76)}
                       needing-defaults))
```

Just remember to keep the function calls inside the call to `merge-with-defaults` to prevent evaluation.